# ng-click inside a infowindow content of google maps

Tags: google-maps, angularjs

Is there a way to create an ng-click angularjs directive inside an infowindow content?

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    map: map,
                    position: pos,
                    content: '<div ng-click="???" class="infowindow"></div>'
                  });
```

Answer (score 21):

You will need to compile the HTML element first with something like

```
var htmlElement = '<div ng-click="???" class="infowindow"></div>'
var compiled = $compile(htmlElement)($scope)
```

then set InfoWindow Content to be something like

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                map: map,
                position: pos,
                content: compiled[0]
              });
```

Comment: i think that you do not need the data attribute compiled[0].data

Comment: @MajoB it actually won't work with .data. It should be compiled[0], no parameter.

Comment: compiled[0].data should be compiled[0].outerHTML

Comment: Thanks Yusuf. I edited my answer with your suggested changes.

Comment: I am trying to use this solution, but using "controllerAs: 'vm'" syntax and not sure 1: what to pass into "$compile(htmlElement)($scope)" in place of $scope, 2: what '???' looks like in 'ng-click="???"', assuming a controller function name of 'myFunction'.

Comment: The above exemple does not work for me. I only use compiled[0] instead of compiled[0].outerHTML. With outerHTLM, my directives weren't working.

Comment: @tyko You saved me. Just use compiled[0].

Comment: @SungKim Thanks. I updated the answer for the second time. Didn't use google maps for a while but looks like the library is changing :).

Comment: @kebomix Thank you for your great answer!

Comment: You must also ensure your html content is composed of a single root tag, otherwise since we are using index [0] you'll only see the first tag.  So simple rule - enclosed everything in a div, for example.

Comment: @Mr.Bungle Thanks for that. Adding div to the start and end made it work